# Split a string into columns of a table Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file containing many strings, all of the same format. These strings consist of numbers, all of which are used for providing information about a given problem. I am using Pandas to store my data currently, but not in the format I require.

For example, the format of the strings is as follows:

```
10010010000000000000000002
```

which I want to be split as such:

```
1001 0010 00000000 00000000 0 2
```

So the 1st 4 bits will become a column, the 2nd 4 bits, the 3rd 8 bits, the 4th 8 bits, and the last 2 bits each being their own column.

So the table will consist of 6 columns.

Thanks

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pd.read_fwf('file.txt', withds=[4,4,8,8,1,1], dtype='str', header=None)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, just to confirm, what is the "header" referring to?

Comment: `header` refers to the column names, usually the first row of the data file. `header=None` means your data file doesn't have a column names row.

Comment: I just implemented this code, and it gave me a table with just a single column, if I want multiple columns, would I enter their names in the "header" section?